# When conserving angular momentum, about which point(s) should it be calculated?

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames

In my physics problem I have a ball fired at a non fixed bar, which is moving at some velocity, causing them both to stick together and the bar-ball pair to rotate about the new center of mass. About which point(s) should I write my conservation of momentum equation? If I write it about the new com for both before and after, is it important that the bar is originally moving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only outright requirement is that you compute all the angular momenta in your problem around the same center (modulo applying the parallel axis theorem to break the angular momentum of extended bodies into of-and-around the CoM parts).

So you can freely chose any single point to use

Now, as with most such "free" choices in physics there are generally some choices which are better than others. Learning to identify which choices are likely to be good simply requires practice. In the case you describe the "obvious" choices are either

- the whole system's center of mass frame
- the center of mass frame of either object
- or the lab frame (i.e. the frame in which the problem is described)